# Pandas: setting value in a multi-indexed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to set a value in a multi-indexed DataFrame. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'a' , 1], [1, 'b', 2], [2, 'a', 3]], columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])
df.set_index(['x','y'], inplace=True)
df
```

gives:

```
        z
x   y   
1   a   1
    b   2
2   a   3
```

and then

```
df.loc[(2,'b')] = 4
df
```

gives

```
        z     b
x   y       
1   a   1   NaN
    b   2   NaN
2   a   3   4.0
```

instead of

```
        z
x   y       
1   a   1
    b   2
2   a   3
    b   4
```

So apparently, Pandas does not understand that the dataframe is multi-indexed and it interprets `[(2,'b')]` as row 2 and column 'b', as if I had written `df.loc[2,'b']`.

How can I achieve what I want ?

Additionally, why is the integer 4 converted into a float ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also is necessary specify column `z`:

```
df.loc[(2,'b'), 'z'] = 4
print (df)
       z
x y     
1 a  1.0
  b  2.0
2 a  3.0
  b  4.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much! There is still the mystery of the float conversion, but Pandas works in mysterious ways anyway !